# Java Palindromes revision

Tags: java

Hey I'm just revising for a java examination I have upcoming and I have got stuck in a rut with one question in particular, we are told the answers however I cannot see how they are achieved thus making knowing the answers useless.

[image]

[image]

Any help with this would be appreciated as I'm having lots of trouble wrapping my head aroud the question.

Does it work by running the numbers as 1, 2 ,3 as I can get the answer for question 1 using this method if I skip 3 from the equation however this doesn't make much sense either.

Comment: Hey, welcome to stackoverflow. If you have a question, we need your current progress in order to help you. Please post your code.

Comment: @glubus hey this question is not about creating working code rather than understanding the way already working code works, the code for the questions is within the imgurlinks

Comment: Then this question is off topic, we are not here you help you understand code that other people created. Maybe if you specified very clearly what you do not understand, as well as showing effort of your trying to understand what is going on, people might get convinced to help you.

Comment: I would suggest the you put that code into an IDE, such as Eclipse/NetBeans/Intellij and step through it. If you cannot do that, then use pen and paper. Recursion can be a little tricky to grasp, and this is the absolute best way to get to grips with it.

Comment: What is your question actually? Are you asking how the given solution works?

Comment: @glubus i have stated that i do not understand quite how the number is input into the code and how it runs, does it just run though once with i as 3 or does it run through the array 0-3 each time replacing the value of i, apologies if i have not been clear enough.

Comment: @KAIATTEWELL Do you know how to use a debugger from your IDE?

Comment: @user3437460 yes, that is my issue i can get the answer with pen and paper by running through the code using i's value as 1 then 2 to get the exact value that palindrome 3 gets, however this does not seem the correct method to me.

Comment: @KAI ATTEWELL Pen and paper is the right way. Trough that you understand the code. There is no trick

Comment: @KAIATTEWELL You got the right output with paper and pen but you are not sure whether you derive the output with the correct interpretation. Easy, write out the output with more inputs other than 1 and 2. Then run the program and compare your answer with the actual output. When the actual output is different from yours, then you post it here, telling us what you got. I'm sure you will get a reply. If you tried inputs 1 - 10 and all are correct. You are pretty much on the safe side.

Comment: @Blobonator Hey i have gone through both sides of two sheets of paper now trying to work out how this code runs, i beleive im missing something extremely fundamental which is why i came for external help.

Comment: @KAI ATTEWELL So what exactly do you do not understand? The whole code? The main method? The recursion?

Comment: @blobonator, i think its the recursion. To my understanding The main method takes a number to put into N then prints out the Palindrome function using the number from N as the int the question asks.the palindrome function either takes N-2 N-1 N-2 and prints it, or does the same but runs through an array

Comment: @KAI ATTEWELL: `N` is only used at the first call of the method. The palindrom method itself works with `int i`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to be careful with the stacks in case of recursion. Create a stack while checking such ques. And it turns out to be quite simple.

Considering 1st case N=3

The Top of the stack- Palindrome(3)

```
As Value of i!=0 or 1 so  palindrome (3-2) is the first statement to be called. Hence, pushed at top of the stack.

Now top of the stack, palidrome(1)
i= 1, returns 1 and top popped..

Back to palindrome(3), equals T + PALIDROME(2)+PALINDROME(1)

PALIDROME(2) to top of the stack.
Now for n=2,
Return statement will be       palidrome(0)+palindrome(1)+palindrome(0)
=STS
Top popped, so back to palindrome(3)
Hence palindrome(3)= T+STS+T=TSTST
```

Comment: Whilst this is a good answer to the question, the formatting is appalling. Spend some time with the formatting tools to get something that looks like a professional answer on a professional forum, and you may get some upvotes.

Comment: Hey when using the stack for three how come it is T+Palindrome(2)+Palindrome(1) and not T+palindrome(2)+T?

Comment: @KAIATTEWELL is that not the same thing? The point of the stack is the it is evaluated **top first** - we don't know what `P(1)` is at the bottom of the stack _because we haven't got there yet_. Although obviously `P(1) === T`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Ya.. I am new to stackoverflow. (kind of) and I posted this ans. from my cellphone.. :3 Thanxx Btw... I'll take care of that from the next time. :)

Comment: @KAIATTEWELL Eventually it will be. It's just that Palindrome(2) will be pushed to the stack before the last palindrome(1). palindrome(1) for palindrome(3) will be calculated twice (And it will be calculated again for Palindrome(2)). This is the major reason we avoid recursion as it causes memory overhead.

Comment: @VatsalPrakash Thank you a lot, this has fully helped me understand the question and the method in general.

Answer (score 0):

So lets look at example A:

`N=3` So the first call of palindrome is with `i=3`
The return value from this call is `palindrome(3 - 2) + palindrome (3 - 1) + palindrome (3 - 2)`

This is `palindrome(1) + palindrome(2) + palindrome(1)` This equals to `T + palindrome(2) + T`
Now we look at the call of `palindrome(2)`. This is `palindrome(2 - 2) + palindrome(2 - 1) + palindrome(2 - 2)` what is equal to `palindrome(0) + palindrome(1) + palindrome(0)`. So that is `S + T + S`.

All in all the return is `TSTST`

Comment: So i run the original number 3, find out which values match within that and then run the palindrome for any values that dont give back an S or T(for example palindrome 2). I think i understand this from this answer.

Comment: Yep. That is the thought behind it.